# react-snapshot: addComponentAsRefTo(...) error

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

Following this tutorial: https://medium.com/superhighfives/an-almost-static-stack-6df0a2791319

Getting this error after application is being built: [facebook-react-error](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=119):

> addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded ....

Does anyone know the clue?

**npm ls react** looks like follow:

```
`-- react-snapshot@1.0.4
  `-- react@15.5.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, solved it by removing

> //= require react-server

from /app/javascripts/server_rendering.js

the cause of this error usually is a duplicated load of react as you can read [in this article](https://gist.github.com/jimfb/4faa6cbfb1ef476bd105)